# What is different between SVO logic versus BAN logic?

Tags: authentication

While reading about authentication protocols, I saw on [Wikipedia on Burrows-Abadi-Needham logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Abadi%E2%80%93Needham_logic):

> In some cases a protocol was reasoned as secure by the BAN analysis
> but were in fact insecure.[3] This has led to the abandonment of
> BAN-family logics in favor of proof methods based on standard
> invariance reasoning.[citation needed]

Then in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-45608-2_2.pdf) by Syverson I see:

> In response to this diversity, Syverson and van Oorschot devised a
> logic, SVO, that was intended to unify the above predecessors [SvO94,
> SvO96]

This is fairly technical material -- is there a more layman-level simple description of how the SVO logic improves upon BAN? I am also wondering to what extent the BAN-based logic is actually really "abandoned" in computer security.

Answer (score 0):

**How does the SVO logic improve upon BAN?** 

SVO modifies different aspects of BAN, such as notation, axioms, and analysis steps. Extended notation and axioms make the SVO logic more **expressive**. I provide two examples where SVO is *stronger* than BAN. 

**1. Invalidating Insecure Protocols**

---

SVO notation includes the following in addition to BAN notation:

1. ***P has X***
2. [image: negation]

Now consider **[the Nessett](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/382258.382789)** protocol. 

[image: nessett]
[image: nessett2]

The paper you mentioned says:

> SVO contains both negation and the ability to express possession. It can express who should not get keys in the Nessett protocol.

More precisely, if we do not want an adversary to have the keys, we have to assume:

[image: negation]


We know that the assumption above is not valid. As a matter of fact, the exact opposite is true. If we assume a [Dolev-Yao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolev%E2%80%93Yao_model) adversary, we can drive the following:

[image: adversary]

With the derivation above, we can employ SVO to prove the protocol is insecure. We could not do so using the BAN logic.

**2. Validating Diffie-Hellman Based Protocols**

---

SVO has **The Key Agreement Axiom**.

[image: key agreement axiom]

This axiom makes SVO logic suitable for the analysis of Diffie-Hellman-based key exchange protocols. We cannot apply BAN for such protocols.

**To what extent is the BAN-based logic abandoned in computer security?**

---

BAN logic is not abandoned. Researchers still employ it for verifying certain protocols. You can find the recent papers using it on [Google Schoolar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_ylo=2021&q=ban+logic&hl=en&as_sdt=0,10).